# Running transaction for multiple queries in Cloud Spanner

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have a bunch of DDL and DML statements that I want to run inside a transaction with a specific timeout. I am using python (`google-cloud-spanner`) on the client-side.

Any insight on how to structure the transaction?

Comment: Was there a particular problem with the approach you have tried?

Comment: I was trying to follow https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/transactions but I couldn't understand how to run multiple SQL statements in a transaction. For SQL Server, I use `execute`, `commit`, and `rollback`. Wondering how to do a similar thing in spanner

Comment: @Shrav checking the [Cloud Spanner Python docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/spanner/latest/transaction-usage.html) will help explain things for you. `run_in_transaction()` will automatically handle the commit and rollback so you don't have to manually trigger them. If you need further help, please update your post with more details.

Comment: @Shrav may I know if my comment answered your question? If so, please let me know and I will post it as an answer.

Comment: @DonnaldCucharo Yes, that link helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking the [Cloud Spanner Python docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/spanner/latest/transaction-usage.html) you'll be able to see that `run_in_transaction()` will automatically handle the commit and rollback so you don't have to manually trigger them. Here's the note:

> Rather than calling `commit()` or `rollback()` manually, you should use `run_in_transaction()` to run the function that you need. The transaction’s `commit()` method will be called automatically if the with block exits without raising an exception. The function will automatically be retried for Aborted errors, but will raise on `GoogleAPICallError` and `rollback()` will be called on all others.